# How do i show such text in c codes or c++ codes?

Tags: c

We have to do some project for our semester. So to make the project we are showing our title of project and we want to display our project like this :

```
 ____                                 _   ____        _            
|  _ \ ___ _ __ ___  ___  _ __   __ _| | |  _ \  __ _(_)_ __ _   _ 
| |_) / _ \ '__/ __|/ _ \| '_ \ / _` | | | | | |/ _` | | '__| | | |
|  __/  __/ |  \__ \ (_) | | | | (_| | | | |_| | (_| | | |  | |_| |
|_|   \___|_|  |___/\___/|_| |_|\__,_|_| |____/ \__,_|_|_|   \__, |
                                                             |___/
```

I tried to use `printf` but could not do. I could not accomplish it.

First I tried like this

```
printf(" ____                                 _   ____        _            ");
printf("|  _ \ ___ _ __ ___  ___  _ __   __ _| | |  _ \  __ _(_)_ __ _   _ ");
printf("| |_) / _ \ '__/ __|/ _ \| '_ \ / _` | | | | | |/ _` | | '__| | | |");
printf("|  __/  __/ |  \__ \ (_) | | | | (_| | | | |_| | (_| | | |  | |_| |");
printf("|_|   \___|_|  |___/\___/|_| |_|\__,_|_| |____/ \__,_|_|_|   \__, |");
printf("                                                             |___/ ");
```

And the problem was `\` character was creating problem. If I replace `\` with `\\` it will not appear as I want to.

So how could I accomplish it? :(

Is there any way?

Comment: Do you mean "diary"?

Comment: Yea thanks for reminding me :) typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `puts()` to have newline characters inserted automatically

```
puts(" ____                                 _   ____        _            ");
puts("|  _ \\ ___ _ __ ___  ___  _ __   __ _| | |  _ \\  __ _(_)_ __ _   _ ");
puts("| |_) / _ \\ '__/ __|/ _ \\| '_ \\ / _` | | | | | |/ _` | | '__| | | |");
puts("|  __/  __/ |  \\__ \\ (_) | | | | (_| | | | |_| | (_| | | |  | |_| |");
puts("|_|   \\___|_|  |___/\\___/|_| |_|\\__,_|_| |____/ \\__,_|_|_|   \\__, |");
puts("                                                             |___/ ");
```

or insert newline characters manually.

```
printf(" ____                                 _   ____        _            \n");
printf("|  _ \\ ___ _ __ ___  ___  _ __   __ _| | |  _ \\  __ _(_)_ __ _   _ \n");
printf("| |_) / _ \\ '__/ __|/ _ \\| '_ \\ / _` | | | | | |/ _` | | '__| | | |\n");
printf("|  __/  __/ |  \\__ \\ (_) | | | | (_| | | | |_| | (_| | | |  | |_| |\n");
printf("|_|   \\___|_|  |___/\\___/|_| |_|\\__,_|_| |____/ \\__,_|_|_|   \\__, |\n");
printf("                                                             |___/ \n");
```

Comment: Nice. So it was problem of new line. I thought due to escaping it was not displaying correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Character '\' has a special meaning in C and C++ strings.  It's used as a prefix to get special characters.  For example new line is '\n'. Which by the way you have to add to the end of all your lines.   If you want to output '\' you have to double to make it '\'.

The line

```
printf("|_|   \___|_|  |___/\___/|_| |_|\__,_|_| |____/ \__,_|_|_|   \__, |");
```

Should actually be

```
printf("|_|   \\___|_|  |___/\\___/|_| |_|\\__,_|_| |____/ \\__,_|_|_|   \\__, |\n");
```

Do the for the rest of the lines.   Also on some operating systems like Windows you have to put both newline and carriage return at the end of the string so it should be '\r\n'  at the end not just '\n'

Comment: thanks i did escaping but forgot new line so the code was not working :) thx :)